# PHP session variable not being stored all of the time

Tags: php, session, uwp

I'm trying to implement a post-redirect-get interface using PHP for a UWP app. Shown below is my actual PHP interface. If I access this PHP script via a web browser (Chrome), then a hashed variable is created and stored in $_SESSION. I can verify that this is working via another script that I wrote that prints out all stored session variables.

If I try to access this same script through my UWP app, then a hashed variable is not stored in $_SESSION. Thinking that I somehow botched my UWP code, I wiresharked the network transmissions, and I can see that a hashed variable is being returned in the 303 redirect, but that same variable is not being stored in $_SESSION. This script seems to only not store the variable when accessed via my UWP app. Why would that be?

```
<?php
   include_once '/var/www/errLogger.php';
   include_once '/var/www/hasher.php';
   include_once '/var/www/jsonConverter.php';

   //Get JSON data
   try
   {
      $jsonArray = jsonToArray($_SERVER);
   } catch (Exception $ex)
   {
      echo logger((string)($ex->getLine()), $ex->getFile(), $ex->getMessage());
   }

   //Save JSON to session
   session_start();
   $hash_id = createRedirectHash();
   $_SESSION[$hash_id] = $jsonArray;

   //Generate URL for this post request
   $hashURL = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/php/redirectTest.php?hash=$hash_id";

   //Reply with 303 redirect - 303 is used so GET request can pull requested data
   header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
   header("Location: {$hashURL}");
?>
```

Below is some sample output from my script that prints the stored session variables....

```
Array ( 
     [92ed11ad76704bf1e4fafcc8b4393d36f7f42dcdf0c1b28acd8c66bbdc545cd9] => test
     [f4bdc2c305922e66790fae080587f54a169140f506734061ed4c23c285efa751] => test
     [48d4979004aba405020ee5148dab8823ce450b4cb741953df598061178504398] => )
```

**UPDATE**: After further investigation, I've come to realize that a session is only saved when Chrome on a certain computer is used to access the php script. Accessing the script via Firefox or through Chrome on a different computer results in a session variable not being saved. I have even tried adding session_write_close(); to my script and have not yet seen any difference in behavior...

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini file.

; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path

session.save_path = "/tmp"

Comment: I modified the php.ini file to store session to "/tmp". After a few tests of switching between php.ini files, I can confirm that I am still getting the same behavior and I can see in "/tmp" that only sessions that were created via a web browser are visible. All of my calls through my UWP app still do not store in session.